# Crystal report Vertical Alignment bottom `y` character cut

Tags: crystal-reports

Trying to fix this:

[image]

I used border bottom single but its always the same.

Also with has a line at the bottom `y` is always cut.

Using also can grow has no luck.

Any Idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Increase the Height of your field.